# copy a file with different name in destination directory using COPY in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

Can I copy a file with different Name in Docker image using COPY in Dockerfile. I am trying with below:

```
COPY file /dest/<renamed_file>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can simply do it like `COPY test.txt /dest/test_renamed.txt` without a trailing `/`.

If you put a trailing `/` like `COPY test.txt /dest/test_2/`, it will copy the `test.txt` file (with the same name, of course) into the directory at `/dest/test_2/`.

Comment: Is there a way to copy a directory into another directory and use the same name as in the src without again specifying the directory name again in the dest like you did in your answer with files, but instead of files with directories? I would expect that when the src is a directory and I don't specify a trailing slash at the src, that it then copies the directory itself, but it always copies the contents regardless of trailing slash or not. With a trailing slash I'd expect that it copies the contents.